# regex for floating positive and negative and 6 decimals

Tags: javascript, regex, floating-point, decimal

I am a newbie with `regex`, I need a regex for number between -180 and 180 integer or float with a maximum of 6 decimals

Comment: I'm wondering why you need a regex. Can't you just `x<180 && x>-180`?

Comment: @JanDvorak OP might be trying to search for such a number in a larger string, rather than just validating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that regex cannot validate whether the number is actually between the range you're given - that should be handled by your business logic.

```
^-?\d{0,3}(\.\d{0,6})?$
```

It's probably a much better solution to read in the number, parse it in JavaScript and validate it that way:

http://jsfiddle.net/4dqqh/

```
function isValid(numStr) {
    var float = parseFloat(numStr);
    return Math.abs(float) <= 180 && float.toFixed(6) - float == 0
}

console.log(isValid('-123.23323')); // true
console.log(isValid('-183.23323')); // false
console.log(isValid('-183.233233424')); // false
```

Comment: Well, you _can_ make a regex that only allows values in the desired range, but business logic is a much better place for it.

Comment: `float.toFixed(6) - float == 0` -- Should `1.000000000` be accepted?

Comment: @JanDvorak good point - that would obviously evaluate to 1. It depends on the OP's requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that the value can be converted to a number in the range and precision you require, but a regular expression isn't the tool for that.

```
function numbercheck180(s){
    var n= !isNaN(n= s*1e6)? Math.round(n)/1e6:-181;
    return (n<180 && n>-180 && n+''=== s)
}


numbercheck180('-179.123456')  true
numbercheck180('179.123456')  true
numbercheck180('179.1234561')  false
numbercheck180('-179.1234561')  false
numbercheck180('-181')  false
numbercheck180('180.00001')  false
```